# Есть ли в котлин события (как в C#)?

Tags: kotlin

Есть ли в котлин события (как event в C#)? Цель создать статический объект и наблюдать за ним. При его изменении нужно выполнить какую-то задачу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289168/kotlin-equivalent-of-c-sharp-events

Comment: Такого сахара нет. Легко сделать вручную, но из встроенного по функционалу ближе всего `flow`

Comment: смотря, что именно вы хотите. есть олдскульная либа EventBus (это если хотите мучений). есть RxJava1-2 и ее аналог RxKotlin (новички тратят полгода на изучение Котлтина и 2 года на Rx). есть упощенная LiveData (родная фишка Котлина. она довольно простая, но и ее дефолтные возможности такие же). и есть современный Flow (смесь Rx и LiveData)